# Firestore set doc with merge option true or update doc

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to update a single field in an existed Firestore document.

However, I don't know if there is some difference between using

```
admin.firestore().doc('doc_id').set({name:'Bill'},{ merge: true })
```

or

```
admin.firestore().doc('doc_id').update({name:'Bill'})
```

If the document is:

```
{
  name: Bart,
  age: 18
}
```

Should `.update(...)` just update the field and not remove the field "age" in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference between those two options for existing documents.

The difference between them is only evident for documents that don't exist.  `set()` with merge will create the document if it does't exist, and `update()` will fail if it doesn't exist.